# How to add separate lines (not straight lines!) to facets of a plot from a separate data.frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have two data.frames (shown below)

```
originalData <- structure(list(Channel = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L
), Intensity = c(0.008, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0.003, 0.002, 0.006, 0.011, 
0, 0.008, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.017, 0.006, 0, 0, 0, 0.002, 0.002, 0, 
0.002, 0.004, 0.008, 0, 0.001, 0.001, 0, 0.013, 0.007, 0, 0, 
0.001, 0.002, 0.001, 0.004, 0, 0, 0.009, 0, 0.001, 0.001, 0, 
0.011, 0.174, 0.013, 0, 0.227, 0.003, 0.003, 0.003, 0.253, 0, 
0.009, 0, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.012, 0.003, 0.008, 0, 0, 0.003, 
0.001, 0, 0, 0.005, 0.01, 0, 0.001, 0, 0, 0.015, 0.248, 0, 0.004, 
0.243, 0.004, 0.004, 0.006, 0.185, 0.003, 0.008, 0, 0.002, 0.001, 
0, 0.01, 0.203, 0.017, 0, 0.223, 0.004, 0.003, 0.008, 0.21, 0.007, 
0.006, 0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.199, 0.017, 0, 0.204, 0.01, 
0.229, 0.201, 0.006, 0.003, 0.21, 0.195, 0.241, 0, 0.001, 0.219, 
0.007, 0.222, 0.01, 0.006, 0.248, 0.003, 0.003, 0.007, 0.281, 
0, 0.007, 0.006, 0.002, 0.001, 0, 0.226, 0.01, 0.012, 0.28, 0.002, 
0.24, 0.271, 0.005, 0.007, 0.277, 0.254, 0.268, 0.001, 0, 0.27, 
0.227, 0.004, 0, 0.289, 0.005, 0.255, 0.237, 0.009, 0.013, 0.257, 
0.238, 0.237, 0, 0.001, 0.252, 0.02, 0.017, 0.242, 0.009, 0.008, 
0.008, 0.007, 0.213, 0.009, 0.006, 0.012, 0.003, 0.216, 0.223, 
0.005, 0.172, 0.01, 0.009, 0.191, 0.002, 0.227, 0.251, 0.001, 
0.005, 0.215, 0.2, 0.236, 0, 0, 0.239, 0.019, 0.023, 0.211, 0.008, 
0.012, 0.005, 0.006, 0.291, 0, 0.009, 0.012, 0, 0.277, 0.298, 
0.004, 0.019, 0.022, 0.208, 0.01, 0.008, 0.005, 0.004, 0.204, 
0.009, 0.002, 0.011, 0, 0.223, 0.209, 0.002, 0.022, 0.025, 0.27, 
0, 0.012, 0.007, 0.006, 0.237, 0.011, 0.004, 0.012, 0.01, 0.273, 
0.259, 0.003), PSM = c(11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 
22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 
1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 
10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 
11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 
51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 
24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 
7L, 22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 
50L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 
47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 
52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 
45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 1L, 7L, 
22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 11L, 47L, 10L, 50L, 
1L, 7L, 22L, 24L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 51L, 52L), ProteinName = c("Q9P2N6", 
"Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", 
"Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", 
"Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9P2N6")), row.names = c(NA, -240L), class = "data.frame")

dataToAddLine <- structure(list(Channel = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 
11L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 16L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 
8L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 16L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 16L), Intensity = c(0.001, 
0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.024, 0.018, 0.034, 0.027, 0.001, 0.025, 
0.018, 0.001, 0.21, 0.216, 0.207, 0.215, 0.046, 0.037, 0.034, 
0.019, 0.104, 0.108, 0.106, 0.108, 0.054, 0.05, 0.049, 0.044, 
0.057, 0.062, 0.058, 0.062, 0.042, 0.043, 0.041, 0.04, 0.043, 
0.043, 0.044, 0.043, 0.111, 0.115, 0.114, 0.113, 0.054, 0.053, 
0.048, 0.052), ProteinName = c("Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", 
"Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H7Z6", "Q9H9L4", 
"Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", 
"Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", "Q9H9L4", 
"Q9H9L4", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", 
"Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6", "Q9P2N6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

I can use the first data.frame to generate the plot below

```
ggplot (originalData, aes (Channel,  Intensity, group = PSM)) + geom_line () + 
  facet_wrap (~ProteinName) + 
  stat_summary(aes(y = Intensity), fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="line",group=1, size = 1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image: original data image]

The data has three facets: labelled with  c("Q9H9L4" , "Q9P2N6", "Q9H7Z6"). I would like to use the second data.frame (dataToAddLine) to add a line to each of the three facets. Note that this second data.frame has the same names that specify facets x and y axis coordinates as the first data.frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that (?):

```
ggplot (originalData, aes (Channel,  Intensity, group = PSM)) + geom_line () + 
  facet_wrap (~ProteinName) + 
  stat_summary(aes(y = Intensity), fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="line",group=1, size = 1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Intensity, x=Channel, group=NULL), data=dataToAddLine, color="blue")
```